# Defining a command that applies an inline function to each element in a list and saves the result to multiple commads

Tags: expl3, expansion

I would like to modify/extend a collection of pre-existing macros with an inline code that the user provides as an argument.

Consider we have multiple variables, for instance:

```
\def\mon{Monday}
\def\tue{Tuesday}
```

and we need to define red versions of them:

```
\def\redmon{\textcolor{red}{\mon}}
\def\redtue{\textcolor{red}{\tue}}
```

We would like to have a command that does that for us, say as follows:

```
\newCommandForEach{mon,tue}{red#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

Using expl3 I managed to code the simple variant that does not feed to the inline code the token but instead its name:

```
\NewDocumentCommandRaw{\newCommandForEach}{mmm}{
    \clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{#1} % Parse list
    \clist_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{
        \cs_set:cpn{#2}{#3}
    }
}
\newCommandForEachRaw{mon,tue}{red#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
% defines the following:
\newcommand{\redmon}{\textcolor{red}{mon}}
%    should be \mon -----------------^^^
```

If I store the inline command in a macro I can then chain-feed it the appropriate toke, but I do not know how to properly expand the necessary tokens so that consecutive calls do not re-write the previous definitions. The following calls also take an optional argument that shoudl specify an inline function that will be used as the csname of the input token list.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\jpkNewCommandForEachRaw}{mmm}{
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{#1} % Parse list
\cs_set:Npn\jpk_NewCommandForEach_name_cs:n##1{#2}
\cs_set:Npn\jpk_NewCommandForEach_body_cs:n##1{#3}
\clist_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{
    \tl_set:Nn\jpk_NewCommandForEach_name_tl{#2}
    \cs_set:cpn\jpk_NewCommandForEach_name_tl{
        \jpk_NewCommandForEach_body_cs:n{##1}
    }
}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\jpkNewCommandForEach}{mmmO{##1}}{
    \cs_set:Npn\jpk_NewCommandForEach_bodyraw_cs:n##1{#3}
    \jpkNewCommandForEachRaw{#1}{#2}{
        \jpk_NewCommandForEach_bodyraw_cs:n{\tl_use:c{#4}}
    }
}
%
\jpkNewCommandForEachN{mon,tue}{red#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}[uncolored#1]
\jpkNewCommandForEachN{mon,tue}{blue#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}[uncolored#1]
```

After this, the command \redmon gives a blue ``Monday'', as something has been overwritten. If expansion is applied, the non-expandable \textcolor fails to compile.

How can one create an (unexpanded) inline body function that takes an expanded argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what you want, I used a group to contain the temporary definitions of the three helper macros, which might not be really necessary. Because of this I used the expandable `\clist_map_function:nN` instead of `map_inline`, but that shouldn't really be an issue (the performance difference is very small for `clist`-maps, would be something else for `seq`s, but parsing the `clist` into a `seq` if you don't need it for anything else would then again be slower).

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_foreach:n #1
  {
    \cs_set:Npn
    \exp_not:c { \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_new_name:n {#1} }
      {
        \exp_args:Nc \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_code:N
          { \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_rel_name:n {#1} }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \jpkNewCommandForEach { m m m O{##1} }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \cs_set:Npn \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_new_name:n ##1 {#2}
      \cs_set:Npn \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_code:N ##1 { \exp_not:n {#3} }
      \cs_set:Npn \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_rel_name:n ##1 {#4}
      \exp_last_unbraced:Ne
    \group_end:
    { \clist_map_function:nN {#1} \__jpk_NewCommandForEach_foreach:n }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\uncoloredmon{Montag}
\newcommand*\uncoloredtue{Tuesday}

\jpkNewCommandForEach{mon,tue}{red#1}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}[uncolored#1]
\jpkNewCommandForEach{mon,tue}{blue#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}[uncolored#1]

\show\redmon
```

Results in

```
> \redmon=\long macro:
->\textcolor {red}{\uncoloredmon }.
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do exactly what I wanted! Now, let's try to understnd why.
a) (Why) do we need exp_not:c in ..._foreach:n? Wouldn't \cs_set:cpn work?
b) What is the purpose of exp_last_unbraced? Is it an implicit expansion of the main body after \group_end: ? Is it equivalent to \group_end: \use:e{ ... }?

c) In general, could you shed some light in the expansions? :)

Comment: @user3250177 there are some things in LaTeX which behave differently during `e`-expansion and `c`-expansion (those are just very minor details though), so if you're building a `\csname` you should try to only expand in `\csname`-context, since the `_foreach:n` is used in an `e`-context, I used `\exp_not:c` to make sure the name is really built by `\csname` and not at any step `e`-expanded (in practice the difference between the two types of expansion are rather minor, and most likely a `\cs_set:cpn` would work for all your usages).

Comment: @user3250177 since the definitions of our three helpers is kept local to the group, the `\exp_last_unbraced:Ne` fully expands the loop in an `e`-type expansion before the `\group_end:` runs. It is not equivalent to `\group_end: \use:e {...}` but to `\use:e { \exp_not:N \group_end: ... }` (and since `\group_end:` isn't expandable that is equivalent to `\use:e { \group_end: ... }`). The unbraced versions of `\exp_...` insert the result of the expansion without braces around them (unlike `\exp_args:Ne`, which would result in `\group_end: { ... }` and keep our `\cs_set:Npn` local to the braces).

Comment: @user3250177 if I do not forget about this, I'll add some explanations about the expansions to the answer, but not now...

Answer (score 0):

I modified the input syntax a bit. Also I let it expand on definition so `\redmon` is

`\textcolor {red}{Monday}`  rather than `\textcolor {red}{\mon}` if you need to hold the expansion as `\mon` that could be arranged with a few more `\use:whatever` but if it's not needed, this form is probably simplest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\def\mon{Monday}
\def\tue{Tuesday}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\newCommandForEach{mmm}{
    \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{
        \cs_set:cpe{#2##1}{\exp_not:N#3{#2}{\use:c{##1}}}
}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newCommandForEach{mon,tue}{red}{\textcolor}

%\show\redmon

\redmon

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is convenient. Of course, it does not have the full desired flexibility, as it assumes that #3 is a token.

Comment: @user3250177 as I say you could drop assumptions such as that and add more complication to cope with more input forms, but (a) it helps to start simple and (b) if that's actually enough there's no need to do more.  I may add another version tomorrow if no one else does.

Answer (score 0):

I define `\adorn` with three arguments: a list of “variables” to adorn, a prefix to apply to the name and a template for the “adorned” command, where `#1` stands for the value of the current variable in the loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\adorn}{mmm}
 {% #1 = list of parameterless commands
  % #2 = prefix
  % #3 = template
  \foo_adorn:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__foo_adorn_do:nn {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \foo_adorn:nnn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__foo_adorn_do:nn { \cs_set:cpn { #2 ##2 } { #3 } }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \exp_args:Ne \__foo_adorn_do:nn { \exp_not:c { ##1 } } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\mon{Monday}
\def\tue{Tuesday}

\adorn{mon,tue}{red}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
  
\begin{document}

\mon, \tue

\redmon, \redtue

\texttt{\meaning\redmon}

\texttt{\meaning\redtue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I do instead

```
\adorn{mon,tue}{red}{--#1--}
```

the output will be

[image]

Note that if you change the meaning of `\mon` you also change automatically the meaning of `\redmon`.

If this is undesired, then replace `\exp_not:c` with `\exp_not:v`. With the `\textcolor{red}` wrapper you'd get

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I didn't pick this one as the answer of Skilmon is gently more flexible, but I am sure one could edit this to achieve the full result. However, your approach seems simpler, and perhaps has its own elegance. Is this due to the use of cs_new_PROTECTED? What is the purpose of protecting the new commands? Could you perhaps add a short explanation of your approach?